# MySQL5.7 Find_In_Set alternative

Tags: mysql

I have a table that contains User information from different countries. Information like - `Name`, `Country`, `LastLoginDate`, `IsUpdated`, `Certification`.

This table has 1.5 million rows. Now to filter this, I have a stored procedure that takes input as - 
`UserNames` = `'John, Matt, Robin'`

And the query looks like -

```
SELECT Name, Country, LastLoginDate FROM Users
WHERE find_in_set(Users.Name, UserNames) <> 0
;
```

The `EXPLAIN` statement says that this has `type` - `ALL` and doesn't use any index. Is there any way I can take the text and create a table with input values and join to my core table which will help using index and faster ouput?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @Lennart MySQL 5.7

Comment: split usernames and insert each token in a temp table, then you can join against that table: `SELECT Name, Country, LastLoginDate FROM Users u JOIN TMP t ON u.name = t.name`

Comment: @Lennart How to split the text and insert each token in temp table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the search parameters and use a join instead. Example

```
-- Some data to test with
CREATE TABLE testdata ( x varchar(100) not null primary key );
INSERT INTO testdata (x) VALUES ('a'),('c'),('e');

-- This can be a temporary table, add all numbers up to
-- the maximum number of tokens in parameter string
CREATE TABLE positions (pos int not null primary key);
INSERT INTO positions (pos) VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5);

-- Table that hold tokens, this can also be a temporary table
CREATE TABLE tokens (token varchar(100) not null primary key);

-- Split the search string in individual tokens, and store in table
INSERT INTO tokens
SELECT substring_index(
           substring_index(T.tokens, ',', p.pos)
         , ','
         , -1
       ) as token
FROM (SELECT 'a,b,c,d' as tokens) as T -- 'a,b,c,d' is the search string
JOIN positions p
  ON char_length(T.tokens) 
    - char_length(replace(T.tokens, ',', '')) 
    >= p.pos - 1;

-- Get all testdata that matches search string
SELECT t.*
FROM testdata t
JOIN tokens tt
    ON t.x = tt.token;

x
-
a
c
```

Comment: How does that split a sting with an arbitrary number of components?  I see no loop.  If you are creating a temp table, I cringe at the performance.

Comment: It does not, you need to fill the position s table with the maximum number of tokens

Comment: If max amount of tokens is not limited than dynamic `position` table generation needed. Nevertheless it can be effective solution. I would additionally think about indexing the tokens table...

Comment: @Akina, if long patterns are common, one can make POSITIONS a permanent util table and call it, say NUMBERS. The max length of varchar is 65536, but the separator token can be at most half of that. The TOKENS table has a primary key, what additional index are you thinking of?

Comment: *what additional index are you thinking of?* oops, I didn't see that `tokens.token` is PK. *one can make POSITIONS a permanent util table and call it, say NUMBERS.* Before 8+ I always recommended to create `NUMBERS(number)` table in `mysql` database with numbers 1..1000 stored for similar purposes.

Answer (score 2):

For a million rows, don't use

```
WHERE find_in_set(Name, 'Leslie,Dana,Ricky') <> 0
```

because `INDEX(Name)` will not help.

Instead, use

```
WHERE Name IN ('Leslie', 'Dana', 'Ricky')
```

and have that index.

As for constructing that string, I recommend doing it in your application code, not SQL.

Comment: For using `IN` I need split string not text. Also I don't understand "doing it in your application code". The stored procedure is supposed to take in comma separated text.

Comment: @Hello.World - But what called the Stored Proc?  Java code?  PHP? ...

Comment: I think there is an API that calls code when a User selects a filter from drop down in front end. I think they use C # and ORM

Comment: I would put my effort in building optimal queries in C# / ORM.

Comment: How? I mean if I need I can use Python too. Do you think that can help?

Comment: You have already learned both ORM and SQL, in spite of the ORM trying to hide SQL from you.  I don't know which will be harder to learn -- the contorted code to do the task in SQL, or yet another language.

Answer (score 0):

Really simple:

```
set UserName = '["John", "Matt", "Robin"]';

SELECT `Name`, `Country`, `LastLoginDate` FROM `Users`
WHERE `Name` in (select * from JSON_TABLE(UserNames, "$[*]" COLUMNS(`name` varchar(45) PATH "$"))`js`);
```

The advantage of using IN over FIND_IN_SET is that IN uses indexes so it is faster.

This method can also be used in a MySQL function as the other method of using PREPARE is not allowed in a MySQL function.

The above is done by breaking the JSON into values by making the JSON a JSON_TABLE